# Angular 4 detect horizontally scrolling on an element

Tags: angular

How can I detect horizontally scrolling on an element

I have a div in a containing div that scrolls left to right.

I want to detect the when the div is scrolling.

I can use this to detect the window scrolling, but how do I detect one element scrolling

```
@HostListener("window:scroll", []) onWindowScroll() {
    console.log('scrolling');
    const verticalOffset = window.pageYOffset
        || document.documentElement.scrollTop
        || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
}
```

Comment: Build an Angular directive with @HostListener and attach it to the element you wan't to detect scrolling on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can handle the scroll event of the container div:

```
<div class="container" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
  <div class="content">
    Some content 
  </div>
</div>
```

```
onScroll(event: Event) {
  console.log(event);
  ...
}
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzjrwm) for a demo.

Comment: this is not really realiable solution.. In my huge list on IE is a big problem while continues scroll UP, DOWN and LEFT, RIGHT. Looking for solution to detect only horizontal scroll